# Highcharts customising gridlines and axis dashstyle?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I've setup a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Sjzty/

I want my x-axis and y-axis lines to be shortDash like the gridLines, I also want their to be a final gridLine at the end of my graph (where ATM there isn't).

My colleague would also like to have the days of the week sitting above the day in the 2nd view.

Have we hit the limit in customising here? I can't see anyway to get these styles from the Highcharts API? You can't give a dashStyle to the axis, and u can't end on a gridLine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your graph to end on a gridline you should add this to the xAxis config in the highcharts config object:

```
endOnTick: true,
showLastLabel: true
```

As for getting the days of the week to appear you should look into the datatime axis type. It will make your life easier and allow you to customise the labels: http://jsfiddle.net/kSkYN/1/